# Create Dynamic table with different row span for each item in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC environment. I want to display images from controller with different row span attribute. If I got the type [column from database] as "2" row span should needs to be set to "5"

Kindly Help me for the same.

```
 @foreach (RekoMart.Models.ProductBannerImage prod in ViewBag.ProductImage1)
           {

              <tr>
                          <td rowspan="@(prod.Rowspan).ToString()">
                               <a  href='@Url.Action("ProductDetail", "Home")?product=@Url.Encode(prod.productid.ToString())' title='@prod.productname' > 
                                  <img src="@Url.Content(prod.imageurl)"  height=158 width=280 /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                               </a>
                          </td>

                          </tr>




           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 <td rowspan="@(prod.type == 2 ? 5 : 0)">
```

Comment: I want html something like this                                <table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td rowspan="2">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>

Comment: @SiddheshAdarkar....sorry i m not getting you what actually you want.. this answer will work as per question.. plz explain clearly what actually you want..

Comment: Dear Friend...  I  need to bind 3 images on the home page.  In first row there will be two image..one with row span =1 and other will be with row span ="2" In the second row , there will be only single image with row span =1